# How can I reference the text of a UITextField in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to reference the text of a `UITextField` so I can use it in different places within my app.

```
@IBOutlet weak var mealNameUITextField: UITextField!

@IBAction func nextButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    mealNameBeingCreated = String(mealNameUITextField.text)
    print(mealNameBeingCreated)

}
```

It's giving me the error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Can anyone tell me the correct way to reference the text? Also, it might be good to mention I want to use this info in a global variable.

Comment: Do you check outlet of `mealNameUITextField`?

Comment: Yes, I just rechecked the outlet. Same result.

Comment: I mean that outlet from storyboard or xib is visible?

Comment: storyboard, but I found the problem. Just needed "!" at the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write like this:

```
@IBAction func nextButton(sender: AnyObject) {

  let mealNameBeingCreated : String = mealNameUITextField.text!
  print(mealNameBeingCreated)

}
```

Comment: error: value of optional type "String?" not unwrapped.

Comment: i think you dont need to put `: String`

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBAction func nextButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let mealNameBeingCreated:String = self.mealNameUITextfield.text!
    print(mealNameBeingCreated)
}
```

OR

```
@IBAction func nextButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let mealNameBeingCreated = self.mealNameUITextfield.text!
    print(mealNameBeingCreated)
}
```

The value returned by the textfield is an optional and we have to unwrap it using **"!"** symbol

The syntax depends on the version of the Swift language you are working on. I am using XCode 7.2 which supports swift 2.1.1